# Closing Excel Window that's open VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have code that checks if an excel file exists. If the file already exists then I want to append to the document. But the user might already have the excel file open and in the foreground. How can I close that excel file window? (It would be the equivalent of hitting the x in the excel file's window)

I've tried the following:

```
XLName = "excel2close.xlxs"
'Set oxlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'EDIT: Not correct
'Set oxlApp = GetObject(", Excel.Application")  'EDIT: Syntax error
'Set oxlApp = GetObject(XLName, Excel.Application)  'EDIT: Error 
'429': ActiveX component can't create object

Set oxlApp = GetObject(XLName, "Excel.Application") 'EDIT: Error
'432': File name or class name not found during Automation operation

'Returns Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
oxlApp.Workbooks(XLName).Close SaveChanges:=False

'Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property method
oxlApp.Workbook(XLName).Close

'Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property method
oxlApp.Window(XLName).Close

'Returns Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
oxlApp.Windows(XLName).Close
```

I've also tried all of these with the full path, not just the name.

Comment: You are creating a new excel app, seperate from any that are open, and then you are searching that app for workbooks. If you want to search the current open excel app just search within `Application.Workbooks` dont `CreateObject`.

Comment: If Excel is already running you need to use `GetObject`, not `CreateObject`.

Comment: @Toddleson Thanks for your response! I'm new to VBA so I might have interpreted this wrong. I put: `Application.Workbooks(XLName).Close SaveChanges:=False` and I got a compile error. Method or data member not found.

Comment: @lagercj If you're in Excel VBA that will work, but looking at the tags, i think you're in Word VBA, try `GetObject`

Comment: A new session does not contain any open workbook, so it is not possible to close anything. If the document is open you should use GetObject to obtain the existing Excel Session. `Set oxlApp = GetObject(", Excel.Application")`. Even so, you have to check if such a workbook is open in the found session. Many open session may exist, or even one, but without the workbook you need being open.

Comment: When I use GetObject, I'm getting an automation error. Invalid Syntax @FaneDuru

Comment: Ups... Try it like `GetObject(,  "Excel.Application")`... But i is possible that such an open session to not exist. That's why an error handler should be provided. Something like `On error Resume Nex` then the object setting, followed by `If Err.Number <> 0 Then`. This mean that a session exists. Otherwise, you should use `CreateObject` and be sure that any document cannot be open, if you do not open it in code...

Comment: @FaneDuru I'm getting the error above. I edited the code in the question. It seems like VBA can't find the file at all. I added On error Resume Next but it seemed to just skip the line I added. Nothing changed.

Comment: You did not use any correct way... I will post a relevant answer.

Comment: Please, test, try understanding the answer I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code and try understanding it:

```
Sub ExcelSessions()
   Dim XLName As String, oxlApp As Object, wb As Workbook, wbOp As Workbook
   XLName = "excel2close.xlsx" 'be careful, you used an inexisting extension (xlxs)...
   
   On Error Resume Next
    Set oxlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'if an existing open session exists, it will be set in this way
    If err.Number <> 0 Then   'If no open session exists:
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        Set oxlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'create a new session
    Else                      'If an existing session could be set, check if the necessary workbook exists:
        For Each wb In oxlApp.Workbooks
            If wb.Name = XLName Then Set wbOp = wb: Exit For 'Only if it exists, it is set
        Next
    End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not wbOp Is Nothing Then  'if the necessary workbook has been found:
       wbOp.Close              'it is closed
  Else
        MsgBox "No document named """ & XLName & """ exists in the found open session."
  End If
End Sub
```

Now, `GetObject` will set the first found session. But if more than one session exist, the workbook you search for may not be found in the found open session...

In such a case there are two options to be explored:

1. If **you are sure that the workbook is open** and **you know its full path**, you can obtain the necessary session in the next way:

```
Sub getExcelSessByWbFullName()
   Dim XLName As String, oxlApp As Object, wb As Workbook
    
     XLName = "full name of  excel2close.xlsx" '"C:\yourFolder\excel2close.xlsx"
    Set oxlApp = GetObject(XLName).Application
    oxlApp.Workbooks(Right(XLName, InStrRev(XLName, "\"))).Close
    'oxlApp.Quit 'if you want quiting the session you must uncomment this line
End Sub
```

2. If you only think it may be open and also **many session may be open** I can show you a more complicated method to found all open sessions and check in each if them if the searched workbook is open. If open, close it (and the session, too, if you want that). But I will post it after you test the previous codes and prove that you understand what they are doing...

Comment: @lagercj Didn't you find some time to test the above suggestion(s)? If tested, didn't they solve your problem?

Comment: thank you for your answer! It worked and closed the excel I was working on. Sorry for the delayed response!